# one content div and few variety of tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tabs, accordion

i have two different menus, one is tab menu, the other one is accordion menu.
i want to organize some variety of tabs for one container, i mean there will be various numbers of tab "ul" that will be in accordion menu, but the problem is that for the tab menu there only can be one tab ul that defined by ID, not by class, but i want at least 3 or more, anyway u can see all the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6tA/2/

U can see from there that the links of Tab Menu 2 and 3 doesnt change the content in container, that's the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `id="gstabs"` from the first ul and update your HTML as such:

```
<div id="gstabs">
<ul id="menu">
...
</ul>
</div>
```

Whatever library you're using to do the tabs is only affecting the children of the element with an id of 'gstabs'